# Actionscript 3 - loop thru GridItems when I have the name/id

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to Actionscript 3 and have a question about Grid, GridRow and GridItem.  I have a 3 X 3 grid.  3 rows, 3 columns.  I can put an id or name on the GridItem objects and have done so.  How can I loop thru these?  Here is the grid:

```
    <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.containers.GridItem;
    public function init():void {

            griditem0.setStyle("borderStyle","solid");
            griditem0.setStyle("borderThickness",3);
    /* want to loop here */         
    }
]]>
  </mx:Script>

<mx:Grid id="myGrid" x="77" y="59" visible="true" width="300" backgroundColor="#F50F45" height="300">
    <mx:GridRow id="row1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridItem id="griditem0"   width="100%" height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem id="griditem1"   width="100%" height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem id="griditem2"  width="100%" height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridRow id="row2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem3"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem4"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem5"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridRow id="row3" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem6"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem7"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" id="griditem8"  height="100%" >
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

I've tried looping using an array to hold the ids or names and using the parent container which is the row to get the children, but since I have the name/id it seems it should be easier than this.  I tried to concatenate "griditem" with the index of the loop, but that didn't work.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain a little better what you are trying to do once you get access to the 'griditems'?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `mx.containers.Grid` doesn't have a 'children' attribute nor does if offer any direct access to the GridItems. This was apparently done intentionally because the only route to the GridItems, via the Grid is, `myGrid.layoutObject.target.createdComponents[0].createdComponents[0]`. However the layoutObject is protected so although you can place a Watch on that expression, you will not be able to access it directly.

The best way I can think of is similar to what you have already done.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<8;i++){
    var gridItem:GridItem = this['griditem'+String(i)];
    trace(gridItem.colSpan);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input.  I've been trying to use this: (from this site)

```
public static function getGrandChildByName(
     parent : DisplayObjectContainer,
     child : String,
     grandchild : String) : DisplayObject {
var child_obj : DisplayObject = parent.getChildByName(child);
var child_container : DisplayObjectContainer = child_obj as DisplayObjectContainer;
return child_container.getChildByName(grandchild);
}
```

I am writing a custom component and adding a grid, then 5 grid rows, then 5 elements (grid items) per row.  I set the styles for the grid items, etc. , and it displays o.k.  I want to allow user to update the styles, say to change the background color of a grid item or the border thickness - that kind of stuff.  As I create each grid row and grid item, I insert a name for each.  For Grid Row it is "row" with the row number, like this: "row0", "row1", etc.  For the grid items, the name assigned is like this: "item00", "item01", etc. which is "item" concatenated with row and column number.  The routine works o.k. until the return.  Seems to always return null.  I trace the row and item names as they are assigned and that looks o.k.  In order to do setStyle, I guess I would have to cast the result as a GridItem, don't know about that yet.  I would just like to not get a null back from the routine. I can update the title of the grid and change it's style without any issue.  It's just the grandchildren of the grid (gridItems) that is giving me the problem. I hope this makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you accidentally left out the link to the site you referenced. Also, what arguments are you passing to the `getGrandChildByName` function?